# Calculate the deeper's branch in Tree

Tags: haskell

I need Help for solve this problem:
I must calculate the length of the deeper's branch consisting of only elements "A" in a BSTree.

I tried with this:

```
data El = A | B deriving (Eq,Show)

data BSTree a = Nil | Node a (BSTree a) (BSTree a)
testBST :: BSTree El
testBST = Node A (Node A (Node B Nil Nil) Nil) (Node A Nil (Node A (Node B Nil Nil) Nil)) 

pathTree_hlp :: Int -> Int -> BSTree El -> Int
pathTree_hlp curmax prevmax Nil = max curmax prevmax
pathTree_hlp curmax prevmax (Node A l r) = pathTree_hlp (curmax+1) prevmax l + pathTree_hlp (curmax+1) prevmax r 
pathTree_hlp curmax prevmax (Node B l r) = pathTree_hlp 0 (max curmax prevmax) l + pathTree_hlp 0 (max curmax prevmax) r

pathInTree :: BSTree El -> Int
pathInTree Nil = 0
pathInTree (Node B l r) = 0
pathInTree (Node A l r) = pathTree_hlp 0 0 (Node A l r)
```

The result should it be 3, but my code returns 17 (?)
Can you help me for solve this problem?

Thanks to all.

Comment: You are using `+` to merge the results of the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this two lines, i change **sum** of your functions with l and r branches to **max** of them:

```
pathTree_hlp curmax prevmax (Node A l r) = max (pathTree_hlp (curmax+1) prevmax l) (pathTree_hlp (curmax+1) prevmax r)
pathTree_hlp curmax prevmax (Node B l r) = max (pathTree_hlp 0 (max curmax prevmax) l) (pathTree_hlp 0 (max curmax prevmax) r)
```